# is there a way to use NETWORKDAYS or NETWORKDAYS.INTL function in excel with no weekends?

Tags: excel, office365

I'm trying to calculate the number of hours between 2 datetimes in excel while excluding non-work hours so excluding (23:00 -> 07:00) and I found the NETWORKDAYS very useful but its strange that I cannot seem to set weekends to be empty.
[image]

I'm using this line that excludes Fridays

```
=(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(F2,G2,16)-1)*("23:00:00"-"07:00:00")+IF(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(G2,G2,16),MEDIAN(MOD(G2,1),"23:00:00","07:00:00"),"23:00:00")-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(F2,F2,16)*MOD(F2,1),"23:00:00","07:00:00")
```

I'm using NETWORKDAYS.INTL since it gives the option to set the weekends but I can only chose one of 17 values all of them have either 1 or 2 days of weekend. is there a way to set this to be empty?

Comment: If you want to get the difference between two date-times, and ignore weekends and holidays, why use `NETWORKDAYS` at all?  Just subtract one datetime from the other. It might help you to understand this better by doing an internet search regarding how Excel stores date/times.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear in my description so I updated it. I need to exclude non work hours 23:00 -> 07:00 each day from the total of hours

Comment: There's still no need to use `NETWORKDAYS`. It has nothing to do with excluding hours; only Days.

Comment: "using this line that excludes Fridays".. do you mean your weekend is defined as friday, saturday n sunday?